# How to process specific rows in a two dimensional array

Tags: java

```
public class OutputRowsandColumns
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int cols = 10;
  int rows = 10;
      int[][] myArray = new int[cols][rows];

// Two nested loops allow us to visit every spot in a 2D array.   
// For every column I, visit every row J.
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        myArray[i][j] = 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the code I have so far, My question is; How do I process specific even and odd rows to set all even rows to 0 and all odd rows to 1.

Comment: Modify the update statement of your for loops.

Comment: if(i % 2 == 0) then i is even

Comment: @ZouZou - in what way do I modify it? Do I have to specifically state each even row? Or is there some syntax for even rows? Can I get an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the solutions suggest you to use the modulus operator.

This can be useful for certain cases, but knowing the fact that the default value for an `int` is 0, you can avoid unnecessary computations here.

All you have to do is to modify the parameters of your for loop to only take in account the odd rows.

```
int[][] myArray = new int[rows][cols];

for (int i = 1; i < rows; i+=2)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)     
        myArray[i][j] = 1;
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: What would the code be to make this print so I can double check it for myself?

Comment: @user3537685 `for(int[] arr : myArray){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));}`. You can also use `Arrays.deepToString` for a nested array but in this case it makes the output more readable.

Comment: I am super super new to java so please bear with me, where in my code would this line go? I assume it would need to be within the class but outside the original loop?

Comment: @user3537685 Yes in the main method, after the nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly, you can setup your array as

```
int myArray = new int[rows][cols]
```

Then to process them, just check

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        if(j % 2 == 0)            // even
            myArray[i][j] = 0;
        else                      // odd
            myArray[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** It's important to switch arount the rows/cols in the declaration and the for loop processing else this won't work properly. If we do it the current way you have it, then even columns will be set to 0 and odd columns to 1 instead of rows.

Answer (score 0):

try modulos;;

solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        if((j % 2) == 0)
          //even
          myArray[i][j] = 0;
         else
          //odd
          myArray[i][j] = 1;
  }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0;i< cols;i++){
     for (int j=0;j<rows;j++){
         if (j%2==0){//even
             myArray[i][j] = 0;
         }
         else{
             myArray[i][j] = 1;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rows and columns are actually the wrong way round, so change:

```
  int[][] myArray = new int[cols][rows];
```

to:

```
  int[][] myArray = new int[rows][cols];
```

Then write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            myArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else {
            myArray[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution will give you slightly better performance, as it doesn't use a conditional statement for every combination of column and row. It uses one conditional statement for every row.

```
int[][] myArray = new int[row][col];
for (int i = 0;i < row;i++){
    int val = 1;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        val = 1;
    else 
        val = 0;
    for (int j = 0;j < col;j++){
         myArray[i][j] = val;
    }
}
```